# Why im getting sometimes ObjectDisposeException when closing my application?

Tags: c#, winforms

In Form1 i have this code:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you Sure you want to Exit. Click Yes to Confirm and No to continue", "WinForm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.No)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            else
            {
                this.backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();                
            }


        }
```

Then i have a new class i did:

```
class Core
    {
        public static Form1 form1;

        public Core(Form1 f)
        {
            form1 = f;

        }

        public static float? cpuView(bool pause , CpuTemperature cpuTemp , Form1 f1 , List<string> myData , float? myCpuTemp , Button b1)
        {
            if (pause == true)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                Computer myComputer = new Computer();
                myComputer = new Computer(cpuTemp)
                {
                    CPUEnabled =

                        true

                };

                myComputer.Open();
                Trace.WriteLine("");
                foreach (var hardwareItem in myComputer.Hardware)
                {
                    if (hardwareItem.HardwareType == HardwareType.CPU)
                    {
                        hardwareItem.Update();
                        foreach (IHardware subHardware in hardwareItem.SubHardware)
                            subHardware.Update();

                        foreach (var sensor in hardwareItem.Sensors)
                        {
                            cpuTemp.SetValue("sensor", sensor.Value.ToString());
                            if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Temperature)
                            {
                                sensor.Hardware.Update();
                                cpuTemp.GetValue("sensor", sensor.Value.ToString());                                
                                f1.Invoke(new Action(() => myData.Add("Cpu Temeprature --- " + sensor.Value.ToString())));
                                myCpuTemp = sensor.Value;
                                if (sensor.Value > 60)
                                {


                                    Logger.Write("The Current CPU Temperature Is ===> " + sensor.Value);
                                    b1.Enabled = true;
                                }

                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return myCpuTemp;
        }
```

The exception is on the line:

```
f1.Invoke(new Action(() => myData.Add("Cpu Temeprature --- " + sensor.Value.ToString())));
```

I think the disposed object that make the problem is Form1 it self.

```
System.ObjectDisposedException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146232798
  Message=Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'Form1'.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  ObjectName=Form1
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method)
       at HardwareMonitoring.Core.cpuView(Boolean pause, CpuTemperature cpuTemp, Form1 f1, List`1 myData, Nullable`1 myCpuTemp, Button b1) in d:\C-Sharp\HardwareMonitoring\HardwareMonitoring\Hardwaremonitoring\Core.cs:line 55
       at HardwareMonitoring.Form1.backgroundWorker1_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) in d:\C-Sharp\HardwareMonitoring\HardwareMonitoring\Hardwaremonitoring\Form1.cs:line 427
       at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
       at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
  InnerException:
```

Then what is disposed ? since i didn't do in my code anywhere something to dispose() it.

And maybe the problem is Form1 since im using in Form1 with a backgroundworker and the backgroundworker is using this class and if im closing the program then form1 is disposed but maybe the variable f1 still trying to do something ?

How can i solve it ?

EDIT**

Changed the cpuView function:

```
public static float? cpuView(bool pause , CpuTemperature cpuTemp , Form1 f1 , List<string> myData , float? myCpuTemp , Button b1)
        {
            try
            {
                if (pause == true)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    Computer myComputer = new Computer();
                    myComputer = new Computer(cpuTemp)
                    {
                        CPUEnabled =

                            true

                    };

                    myComputer.Open();
                    Trace.WriteLine("");
                    foreach (var hardwareItem in myComputer.Hardware)
                    {
                        if (hardwareItem.HardwareType == HardwareType.CPU)
                        {
                            hardwareItem.Update();
                            foreach (IHardware subHardware in hardwareItem.SubHardware)
                                subHardware.Update();

                            foreach (var sensor in hardwareItem.Sensors)
                            {
                                cpuTemp.SetValue("sensor", sensor.Value.ToString());
                                if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Temperature)
                                {
                                    sensor.Hardware.Update();
                                    cpuTemp.GetValue("sensor", sensor.Value.ToString());
                                    if (!f1.IsDisposed)
                                    {
                                        f1.Invoke(new Action(() => myData.Add("Cpu Temeprature --- " + sensor.Value.ToString())));
                                    }
                                    myCpuTemp = sensor.Value;
                                    if (sensor.Value > 60)
                                    {


                                        Logger.Write("The Current CPU Temperature Is ===> " + sensor.Value);
                                        b1.Enabled = true;
                                    }

                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception err)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return myCpuTemp;
        }
```

Added a check before the invoke line and also added try and catch.
Is that ok ? Or i should do it another way for the cpuView and the gpuView ?

EDIT**

This is the backgroundworker dowork event in Form1:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            while (true)
            {

                if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (tempCpuValue >= (float?)nud1.Value || tempGpuValue >= (float?)nud1.Value)
                    {
                        soundPlay = true;
                        NudgeMe();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        soundPlay = false;
                        stop_alarm = true;

                    }

                    tempCpuValue = Core.cpuView(pauseContinueDoWork,cpu,this,data,tempCpuValue,button1);
                    tempGpuValue = Core.gpuView(pauseContinueDoWork,data,tempGpuValue,button1);
                    this.Invoke(new Action(() => data = new List<string>()));
                    tempCpuValue = Core.cpuView(pauseContinueDoWork, cpu, this, data, tempCpuValue, button1);
                    tempGpuValue = Core.gpuView(pauseContinueDoWork, data, tempGpuValue, button1);
                    this.Invoke(new Action(() => listBox1.DataSource = null));
                    this.Invoke(new Action(() => listBox1.DataSource = data));                    
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your form is automatically disposed for you when it is closed. It sounds like `Core.cpuView()` is getting called after your form has been closed.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the form is disposed before invoking it.

```
if (!f1.IsDisposed)
{
    f1.Invoke(new Action(() => myData.Add("Cpu Temeprature --- " + sensor.Value.ToString())));
}
```

Additionally, inside some of your for loops you should add a check for cancellation, so the background worker finishes faster.

```
if (CancellationPending) return;
```

And even with this, it's still possible you'll get the disposed exception.  If the form closes after the `IsDisposed` check and before the `Invoke` call, then you'll get the exception.  For this rare case, add error handling and ignore it (this is an exception that's safe to ignore when the application is shutting down).

Comment: Samuel Neff i edited my code can you look please if it's ok or if not show me how it suppose to be ?

Comment: @user2760148, you're partway there.  You added the cancellation check to the background worker, but since cpuview also has a loop and is presumably doing some time consuming work, it should have additional cancellation checks.  I also don't see any added `IsDisposed` checks or error handling.

Comment: I have added the IsDisposed before the invoke lines in the cpuView and the gpuView. And about the cancelltion check i have to try to work about it yet.